# Multiple HTML Pages

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to create HTML Pages with linking in navigation bar via Rmarkdown? `Pkgdown` is a perfect example for this but it links to source code of the package. I am looking for similar functionality with rmarkdown. Any reference please?

Comment: I think "Distill" might be what you are after? https://rstudio.github.io/distill/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in Rmarkdown! You want to look at [Blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) which is all about creating websites, multiple HTML pages, with Rmarkdown.